# When should I use JobService in BroadCastReceiver.onReceive()?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am reading the `BroadcastReceiver.onReceive()` [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver#onReceive(android.content.Context,%20android.content.Intent)) but I do not understand

> If you need to perform any follow up background work, schedule a JobService with JobScheduler

I would be glad if someone could tell me what are the use-cases of such an approach.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It depends on your requirement. What do you want to do after consuming/receiving the broadcast?

Comment: @roshana-pitigala I retrieve GPS coordinates and send an SMS back. It works but I was worried it might not be the best approach

Comment: and not asynchronously

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BroadcastReceiver may cause an [ANR](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/anr#slow_broadcast_receivers) if the work inside `onReceive` takes a considerable amount of time. Because of that, you should consider moving long-running jobs to the worker, such as JobService, or using jetpack WorkManager.

Comment: Thank you for your precious answer. I have a follow-up question just for the sake of curiosity: I can understand why an ANR can be raised if the UI's thread is blocked, but why will it be raised if a background thread is doing a task? Furthermore if the background thread blocks, also the JobService might block